# Google Maps in Angular 7

Tags: angular, google-maps, border

Good day. i have a project in angular that has google map integrated. My problem is i can't add a border Around the GOOGLE MAP WINDOW. and if i add border in css.. it just shows a line on top and bottom left-most side of the gmap window.

here's the component html :

```
<agm-map 
[latitude]="lat" 
[longitude]="lng"  
[zoom]="11.2"
>
</agm-map>
```

this is the component css without border.

```
agm-map {
    height: 550px;
    width: 700px;
    position: relative; right: 100px;
    border: solid white 10px;
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: I think wrapping the agm in a div and giving border to that div will work.

Comment: adding to above comment. try making the outer div `position: relative` and the component as `position: absolute`

Comment: yep. that solves it. thanks